# different email campaign exm sitecore

Tags: email, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecm, sitecore-exm

i want to ask something about email experience manager, im using **version 3.1.**

my case is if i have many product(i want to blast email campaign about that products to my subscribers), for example **product A, product B, and product C**.

I send that email with content **product A** with the csv that has 100 recipients, and then **5 recepients want to unsubscribe** that product and clicked unsubscriber link.

what i want to ask is :

1. if i send **product B**, is it the unsubscribe(5 recipients) still getting email campaign about product B and will not getting email campaign about **product A** ?
2. do i have to set different manager root so the recepient on product A didnt effect the recepients on product B(for example it has the same csv recipents file)
3. the difference between unsubscribe and unsubscribe from all( i did read the sitecore documentation but im still kinda confused, im so glad if you can give me example case)

thank you for your help, im new to sitecore and i kinda lost and the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That depends. In EXM 3.1 you need to define at least one include list and one exclude list. There are two ways to unsubscribe: "unsubscribe" and "unsubscribe from all". "Unsubscribe" adds you to the exclude list, "Unsubscribe from all" adds you to the global opt out list defined on the manager root. So, as an example:

You create one manager root and three campaigns: **product A**, **product B** and **product C**.

Send out **product A** to 100 recipients. 5 people unsubscribe and are added to the exclude list. 3 people unsubscribe from all and are added to the global opt out list.

Send out **product B** using the same include list for **product A**, but a different exclude list. All 100 recipients minus the 3 people in the global opt out list will receive **product B**

Send out **product C** using the same include and exclude list for **product A**. All 100 recipients minus the 5 people in the exclude list and the 3 people in the global opt out list will receive **product C**

2. No, you don't have to. That depends if you use "unsubscribe" (i.e. add them to a exclude list) or "unsubscribe from all" (i.e. add them to the global opt out list defined on the manager root).
3. See above :)

Comment: hi tchami thank you for your help, i understand now ^^. is there a way to see the opt-out list content(i want to know who already unsubscribe from all email) beside from message report?

Comment: Yes, you can view the contents of all lists (including the opt out list) in List Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Unsubscription from emails in ExM is managed via opt-out lists.

So, answer on your question will depend on your settings of Opt-out list. If Opt-out lists are same for 3 emails, then if user will unsubscribe from first email he will not receive second and third email. If Opt-out lists are different then unsubscribe will work separately for each email.

Difference between "unsubscribe" and "unsubscribe from all" is next:

- For "unsubscribe" recipient will be added to opt-out list that is selected for email.
- For "unsubscribe from all" recipient will be added to global opt-out list that is configured on ExM root item. And this recipient will not receive any other emails.

Comment: hi anton its you again! thank you for helping me. where can i see the opt-out list content(recepient who already unsubscribe)? is it on mongodb? sorry im asking too many question :/